# Propositional statements dealing with "only if"

Tags: propositional-calculus

If I have the statement. "I can ride my bike only if tires aren't broken"

and I have P(X) = "I can ride my bike" 
and I have Q(X) = "My tires are broken"

Would the above statement be P -> Not(Q)

Also what would the contrapositive of this be?

in English and predicate..? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you have labelled the statements P(X) and Q(X) rather than just P and Q, since they have no dependence on a variable X.

Comment: Oh is that wrong to use P(X) or Q(X)?

Comment: Not wrong per se, but misleading. P(X) would normally be taken to be an assertion about a variable object, X, such as "X can ride his/her bike" or "X is a prime number". (This is called a predicate.) There is no need to include such a variable for the statement "I can ride my bike" since it is a specific assertion. (A proposition).

Answer (score 1):

We have $P\Rightarrow \neg Q.$ The contrapositive is $Q\Rightarrow \neg P.$

"If your tires are broken, then you cannot ride your bike."

$P$ "only if" $Q$ is really just $P\Rightarrow Q.$ If you can ride your bike, then you know that your tires are not broken. So your initial intuition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's right.

The contrapositive would be $Q\to\lnot P$ ("If my tires are broken then I can't ride my bike").

Answer (score 0):

Given $P$ and $Q$ as you define them, then "I can ride my bike only if my tires aren't broken" is indeed $P\to\neg Q$. The contrapositive $Q\to\neg P$ would be most naturally read as "If my tires are broken, then I can't ride my bike".